# Visual Workflow - Any possibility to use screen choice field in the same screen?

Tags: visual-workflow

We have a flow that has a screen element. In this screen, we have 2 fields:

1. a dropdown list with preset values (in our case field 'Brand')
2. 1 dynamic choice, where we want to show Products

[image: Flow]

We'd like to use the **value selected in the first field to filter in the second field**, as indicated above. Basically a bit how dependent picklists work.

This works fine when the fields are in 2 different screens. As long as you have not clicked 'Next', the value in the first field is not stored and thus our second field tries to filter on a blank value.

Is there any workaround for this in visual workflow **without** splitting the fields up in different screens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find this new dependent picklists Flow Screen Component helpful:

https://medium.com/@alexedelstein/dependentpicklists-a-flow-screen-component-c97dcee1796